# Laravel admin middleware doesn't redirects to dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, admin, middleware

I'm trying to redirect regular user to homepage and admin to a dashboard. In my users table I have column named *role*. One user has **admin** as role value while another one has **NULL**.

This is my AdminMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role != 'admin') {

            return redirect('/home');

        } else {

            return $next($request);

        }
```

This is my LoginController:

```
protected function redirectTo(){

        if (Auth::user()->role != 'admin') {

            return 'home';

        } else {

            return 'dashboard';

        }
```

The Kernel is set as well:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

And finally, these are the routes:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/movies/create', 'HomeController@create')->name('create');
Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@store')->name('store');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function(){

    Route::get('/dashboard', function(){

        return view('admin.dashboard');

    });
});
```

When I log in I get redirected to my homepage no matter if I got logged in as a user with admin as a role value, or as a user with NULL as role value. But if I try to access dashboard 'manually', by writing url in my browser only the user with admin as role value can get the access, so this part works very well. The issue is that I don't get redirected to dashboard if I log in as a user with admin role value. I don't seem to find any error here. Does anybody have a clue where's the catch?

Comment: were you trying to reach 'home' before you were redirected to the login page? and what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: no I don't think so. I can only reach 'home' if I'm logged in. version is 6.6.2.

Comment: were you trying to reach some url and then were redirected to the login page, or did you navigate to the login page yourself?

Comment: I don't navigate to the login page at this point. it's the first page that appears on my localhost. so if I want to access the homepage I have to be logged in. I have admin dashboard set and I want the user to be redirected to the homepage or to the dashboard, depending on assigned role value.

Comment: I got it, it works! I had __construct with $this->middleware('auth') in my HomeController, which I commented, so the login for admin and regular user now actually works